# Is it possible to downgrade vscode *insiders* / download older insider builds?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code Insiders builds. I'd like to downgrade it, because the latest one has a major regression.

Unfortunately there are no links to older versions on [insiders download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), only the most recent one is available. How to donwload old version of vscode insiders?

The links from [relevant github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46089) no longer work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download an appropriate version via direct URL

- first, go to https://code.visualstudio.com/updates and find the version you want
- on top of the page you'll have links to various platforms:
  `Downloads: Windows: User System ARM | Mac: Universal 64 bit Arm64 | Linux: deb rpm tarball ARM snap` - right click the appropriate link, and choose "Copy Link Address" from the menu
- replace `stable` at the end with `insider`, *and* append `-insider` after the version.

For example, universal MacOS package:

```
// stable
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.61.0/darwin-universal/stable

// insiders
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.61.0-insider/darwin-universal/insider
```

**Note: not all stable builds have an insiders equivalent,** you may need to use `1.x.0` to find the insider build.

Answer (score 1):

You can download any build from the following link!

https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/vscode-insiders/1.71.0.20220831#versionhistory